# Application.properties not getting picked up is value is static

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have one simple spring boot application where i need to print value of a property from application.properties file.

Application.properties file is stored inside src/main/resources

Here i am simplifying my problem and giving some sample code i am using in my application.

Here is the code i am trying to get the value.

```
@SpringBootApplication    
public class Application {
@Value("${secret.property}")
static String secret;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}


public static void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Secret key: " + secret);

}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ezetap</groupId>
<artifactId>jasypt-test2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>jasypt-test2</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Output:

```
command: java -jar target/jasypt-test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 

2016-08-09 12:01:12.299  INFO 7350 --- [           main]         com.ezetap.test.Application              : Started Application in 0.825 seconds (JVM running for 1.15)
Secret key: null
2016-08-09 12:01:12.300  INFO 7350 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@339a956c: startup date [Tue Aug 09 12:01:11 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

I am not able to find the reason for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that processing of Value annotation is performed by `BeanPostProcessor` while static things belong to class and not instance of the class. You will only get that value once you have instance created by Spring container. You can move that logic to separate class and create bean of that class with application context in main.

Comment: Thanks .. small thing missed by me